# UIWebView goBack() issues in iOS 5

Tags: ios, caching, ios5, uiwebview, back

I'm displaying a UIWebView to display a mobile website. The website uses ajax and internal hash navigation. I have a back button to go back in history. 
It works fine on iOS 4 and on iOS for the first time after application launch.

After leaving the UIWebView and coming back to it, the back button does not work properly because of the caching. 
Any ideas how we can get the back functionality/history keeping working in iOS5? We have tried several things on the web page, and natively, but no success.

Our current status is that clicking the back button will return to the initial page on the UIWebView, but jump over the intermediate pages.

Comment: we resolved it by changing the web content to use iFrames. We were also able to resolve it by caching the view controller which contains the web view. However, this new behavior might turn out to be a small bug by Apple.